# Response message: java.sql.SQLException: No pool found named: in jMeter

Tags: database, jdbc, jmeter

I am trying to do the Load testing on a new Database `XpressMP`. So I started using jMeter for that. I configured jMeter to make a Select call to our database. Below is configuration-

[image]

And below is the Snapshot for `XMP Select DB`

[image]

And if I start my test in the jMeter, I always get this exception-

```
Response message: java.sql.SQLException: No pool found named: 'ucirrus', ensure Variable Name matches Variable Name of JDBC Connection Configuration
```

What does this exception mean?

I am pretty much sure, this is the problem with my JDBC Request configuration in my previous image. As I am doing this for the first time.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you connect to the DB using the connection string you have set up in the test? Just curious if there is a typo there.

Comment: Yes. I am able to connect to db. I was following the tutorial from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html). If you take a look in that tutorial `JDBC Request section`. They are putting `MySQL` in `Variable Name` text box. And I am not sure what I need to put in my scenario as I am not using MySQL or Oracle, its a different database. So I randomly put it as `ucirrus`

Comment: "I've since found out that the message "No suitable driver" generally 
means that the connection string is wrong - i.e. none of the loaded 
drivers were able to handle it." http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/java-sql-SQLException-No-suitable-driver-td530331.html

Comment: I am not getting `No suitable driver exception`. Take a look into my question again. I am getting this exception `Response message: java.sql.SQLException: No pool found named: 'ucirrus', ensure Variable Name matches Variable Name of JDBC Connection Configuration
`

Comment: One more and this will be my last post as I am out of my league here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412993/java-sql-exception-no-suitable-driver-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you don't use the right variable name.

In JDBC Connection Configuration (within **Variable Name bound to pool**) set:

- Variable Name : ucirrus